# Flow: Cannot assign _ to _ because property _ is missing in _

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I've reproduced my situation in the try Flow editor which can be accessed [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKAhlvMQCYAquBAvGAIxgA+YATK2AMwDc62fGCoAnYgDsAzsQDGGAJZxxYBgG9UYMMQC2cAK7iMALjDi92gEZ4RAGg1gKeSQvHEFSk85HzxAc1QAvuhQBnKKyjIieG54ABSCeCYkZHCUNPg2YBhiUrLu4iaiEtJhSgCUJgBucPIUYOqa2cV54QB0OvqGKkwADPyNOSX5rY7OPm7h3QBEABwyxADsAGzEUFAAtDNQeDPrACwLjACs6wCceKfE6+yUPUvcPRR7R8Q9U-b28lBgsfG0SaRyNRaGUVHQGHtQQ1NFlBi0lK1tE5pL56GApgAJPAweBTfpgIJBVAyJTOWHNUoFYRwyndVRBSLRDBxRiZJq5SllIA).

Here is the code in case something happens to the link:

```
/* @flow */

type PayloadType = 1 | 2 | 3;

type Transaction = {
  amount: number,
  destination: string
}

function create(type: PayloadType, transaction: Transaction): void {
  transaction.amount = 10;
  transaction.destination = "8ca76aff-8fe8-4715-9e9a-2ad0630d45a0"

  if ((type: PayloadType) === 4) {
    transaction.message = "Hello";
  }
}

const transaction: Transaction = {}
create(1, transaction)
```

The error is:

> Cannot assign `"Hello!"` to `transaction.message` because property `message` is missing in `Transaction` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKAhlvMQCYAquBAvGAIxgA+YATK2AMwDc62fGCoAnYgDsAzsQDGGAJZxxYBgG9UYMMQC2cAK7iMALjDi92gEZ4RAGg1gKeSQvHEFSk85HzxAc1QAvuhQBnKKyjIieG54ABSCeCYkZHCUNPg2YBhiUrLu4iaiEtJhSgCUJgBucPIUYOqa2cV54QB0OvqGKkwADPyNOSX5rY7OPm7h3QBEABwyxADsAGzEUFAAtDNQeDPrACwLjACs6wCceKfE6+yUPUvcPRR7R8Q9U-b28lBgsfG0SaRyNRaGUVHQGHtQQ1NFlBi0lK1tE5pL56GApgAJPAweBTfpgIJBVAyJTOWHNUoFYRwyndVRBSLRDBxRiZJq5SllIA).

The line where I assign an invalid property should never get executed. I'm assuming Flow should know this because `type` can never be `4`, therefore the condition will never be true.

**EDIT**: Here's a [link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKAhlvMQCYAquBAvGAIxgA+YATK2AMwDc62fGCoAnYgDsAzsQDGGAJZxxAIWKT6YAN6owYAG54RkxeIBcYSRhHzxAcwA0OsILzmSZOJRr5UAXwG0wmJSsgpKohKSUIZgDNq6xAC2cACu4hgA-ObiKYkARoaOuol4ktK2eFkWVja2fgFCESFyJgDKeDIieBixWk7qnd1VltZ2RWAAFmoTAIIwtnDWGBOJwzV29ZiBTdItSr07oSaq6mAAZEGRR+HBUTEXh3vi7YMY-KjAwMIT8pJgUGknmA8il5DAKH9iBZ8DJ5FB5DIwHA8gArDo9CQUMCUCFgeQ9NIUGJQyQwuEIsA4ERwfAibAfL5E-DiCi1JHiZwTAhWK5PAB0Lj5YAAkhyusQYPisHiMH9kl0wDI4IkcDA8AAPMAIfETMCJCTSyTajAyCbAOHVYgYErpSQM7EsrU6mxgPCyXUWyxWm0YexgVlQaJddKc2p-KY4Zn-Rb+uFBvAhnnNMJSMD2gAUyzw0ooSgA5D0USlLNiYDB-bkcP6rVCoNTEpzubdrhzkWi5Hj0nBG5TSOQsW30QBKPmoAHiIGDK14TPNp7mR4pv04PueCh+qcYPAAUXyeAoRIodCgEvUQ-Mejg8ix8TxUDAs95KYFgTob6YQ76ugAkCuPJQBVuIMAH0k12FNek0XwwE+MAADEwTVLFjV1UkOnJREqRpQwFFKTsZBgFJWTsHsKBrTtLmTEwdiDJxoLwGBTgtR8qKUF8hDfBhODOC4AEJNx3PcD33T9NBgr4AHlxBgaUJXgJABi6HosNpbBnG7ApsWE5CuQ5cQ4AxDk8CEw9nDnFMnF-VcAMU7pQPMkxIOg2CELLfcnWWaF0PhTDqVU+Q8JsAiiLZLNqwwKEXUXNoOiUujNntVpuzVWULFIRsFWIBUMAQbtxyeP5litLUJB6DBuxkOSewE-5AWfNNYIAJWM4yChEarxS3WqJwgqYWTVSF1Nbe8wJbZxaEkP1JG7fFJjUPUDTvS0tx9O1YKkgh8oghBSsK7tcpEABrDzdSq0agRcSaHSxMKDK5dqdttdStUWY6UNLcsQR6JQ8FHFy6sc5htTLYFQXBbEwAAIlaeRbHEABZUpyjwSHrvggH9k4YHPrBrEJCh3cCm06KlEhrYhBhuHEbKYgKkg1Bv1ggAeMBlEBXU4HvL0FF87C6QCv4FkmQwCAAPks2CqF09kCE5nsVJwgWwAqcRDGnf56yhgSyZ-MCQPOlMqhJ8QaMKJxdFsjB7KfEwjYcpQXji-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-gQL+eAf7uX-oA4BmswEcggVA2B8DLBIMMMYJQaDGA0NwRgmRutaDmEYGQpIqR0iNLoWQkxyM0FqIYvAXRfij6uhMvuWeLZzDeI9ovaxB9c52NIcMomh4xlPD9FYeBn5YLqB6AJSZ7lypmXgegY5QA) to a more realistic example.

Comment: What’s the situation causing you to write incorrectly-typed code that should never run? Some kind of macro expansion?

Comment: Flow will also report an error on the `transaction.message` assignment even if the conditional is changed to `if (false)`. Additionally, if you remove the type cast and just write `if (type === 4)`, Flow will correctly complain that `number literal 4 is incompatible with enum`.

Comment: Do you know why it reports the error with `if (false)`? Would have thought when it parses the text it would know to ignore the statement.

Comment: Even code that doesn’t run should typecheck. This is the way it works in almost every language. So, > What’s the situation causing you to write incorrectly-typed code that should never run? Some kind of macro expansion?

Comment: @Ry- I added an example thats closer to my actual situation.

Comment: With this one, I was hoping flow would detect all the scenarios where `create` is called (in this case 2 secenarios) and then know that the code will never try to add the property to the incorrect type.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem here is not that error appear, but that error appear too late, if to remove casting of the `type` in `if` statement error will appear earlier, what I belive is more expected result.

```js
/* @flow */

type PayloadType = 1 | 2 | 3;

type Transaction = {
  amount: number,
  destination: string
}

function create(type: PayloadType , transaction: Transaction): void {
  transaction.amount = 10;
  transaction.destination = "8ca76aff-8fe8-4715-9e9a-2ad0630d45a0"

  if (type === 4) {
    transaction.message = "Hello";
  }
}

const transaction: Transaction = {}
create(1, transaction)
```

[Flow Try for change](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKAhlvMQCYAquBAvGAIxgA+YATK2AMwDc62fGCoAnYgDsAzsQDGGAJZxxYBgG9UYMMQC2cAK7iMALjDi92gEZ4RAGg1gKeSQvHEFSk85HzxAc1QAvuhQBnKKyjIieG54ABSCeCYkZHCUNEI2YBhiUrLu4iaiEtJhSgCUJgBucPIUYOqa2cV54QB0OvqGKkwADPyNOSX5rY7OPm7h3QBEABwyxADsAGzEUFAAtDNQeDPrACwLjACs6wCceKfE6+yUPUvcPRR7R8Q9U-b28lBg8bQqdAw9mV6vYBs1SuJWtonNJfPQwFMABJ4GDwKb9MBBIKoGRKZxZQYtDzCQkQ7qqIKRaIYOKMTJNXIQspAA)